# Guidance needed | Optimization challenge. Would love to get some inputs 

Tags: optimization, neural-network, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I need some guidance on how to approach for this problem. I've simplified a real life example and if you can help me crack this by giving me some guidance, it'll be awesome.

I've been looking at public optimization algorithms here (https://www.cvxpy.org/) but I'm a noob and I'm not able to figure out which algorithm would help me (or if I really need it).

**Problem:**

x1 to x4 are items with certain properties (a,b,c,y,z)

I have certain needs:

Parameter   My Needs
a          150
b          800
c          80

> My goal is get all optimal coefficient sets for x1 to x4 (can be
> fractions) so as to get as much of a, b and c as possible to satisfy
> needs from the smallest possible y.

**These conditions must always be met:**

1)Individual values of z should stay within threshold (between maximum and minimum for x1, x2, x3 and x4)

2)And Total y should be maintained within limits (y <=1000 & y>=2000)

**To illustrate an example:**

```
x1                          
Each x1 has the following properties                            
a   20      Minimum z   10      Maximum z   50
b   200                     
c   0                       
y   300                     
z   20
```

```
x2                          
Each x2 has the following properties                            
a   30      Minimum z   60      Maximum z   160
b   5                       
c   20                      
y   50                      
z   40
```

```
x3                          
Each x3 has the following properties                            
a   20      Minimum z   100     Maximum z   200
b   200                     
c   15                      
y   200                     
z   40
```

```
x4                          
Each x4 has the following properties                            
a   5       Minimum z   100     Maximum z   300
b   30                      
c   20                      
y   500                     
z   200
```

One possible arrangement can be (not the optimal solution as I'm trying to keep y as low as possible but above 1000 but to illustrate output)

**2*x1+2*x2+1*x3+0.5*x4**

In this instance:

```
Coeff x1    2       
Coeff x2    2       
Coeff x3    3       
Coeff x4    0.5
```

This set of coefficients yields

```
                    Optimal?
total y 1550        Yes
total a 162.5       Yes
total b 1025        Yes
total c 95          Yes
z of x1 40          Yes
z of x2 80          Yes
z of x3 120         Yes
z of x4 100         Yes
Lowest y?           No

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!
```